# Can we make custom filters in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know there are some filters available in angularjs like `**currency**`, `**number**`.

```
{{ value | currency }}
```

Is there any filter available for Phone number formatting?

And can I make my own filter?

```
{{ Phone-value | phoneFilter }}
```

I want to make my own `**phoneFilter**`.

Comment: *"can I make my own filter"* ... yes... is outlined in the docs and easy to search the web for angular custom filter tutorials. Not hard to type *"filter"* in search box of documentation site.

Comment: How to create filter in Angularjs? Not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom filters in angularjs.

```
app.filter('phoneFilter', function() {
return function(input, param1(optional)) {

var result;

//filtering code

return result;

}

});
```

you can use this filter exactly as the standard filters in the view i.e. {{ Phone-value | phoneFilter }}

Hope this helps.

Comment: input in the function will be the Phone-Value?

Comment: yes, it will be the Phone-value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible to make custom filters.
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sf5n2zu/) is just an example of that.

Code:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('phone', function () {
    return function (phone) {
        // phone is the model value
    }
});
```

In your view `{{ phoneNumber | phone}}`

[Angular docs for filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). There's an example of another custom filter in the docs.

A repository with a lot of useful custom filters: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter